# Default media players on Lollipop does not play video and audio files recorded through my app

Tags: java, android

I have created an application through which I can record audio and video clips. However once I save the file I cannot play the files using the Lollipop default players. However I can play the same file using MX player.

Also if I move these same recorded files to a lower version of android, it plays the files using the default phone players.

Code:

```
Log.e("videopath","videopath");

AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();

File root1 = new File(GoaPoliceApp.reportPath);
if (!root1.exists()) {
      root1.mkdirs();
}

file = new File(root1,"Vid_Recorded_on_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4");

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
}     

fis.close();
fos.close();
mType = 1;
aMedia.setmNMediaType(mType);
aMedia.setmNMediaPath(file.getAbsolutePath().toString());
aMedia.setmNPublished("1");
aMedArr = new ArrayList<Media>();
aMedArr.add(aMedia);
GoaPoliceApp.mMedArr.addAll(aMedArr);
/*aDetails.mMediaArr.add(aMedia);
GoaPoliceApp.mReportArr.add(aDetails);*/
//showMail();

Log.e("videopath",file.getAbsolutePath().toString());
```

Comment: Probably wrong unsupported format or malformed file format causing default players to render error. MX is probably more fault safe

Comment: Provide more details on exactly what/how you are creating and what formats lollipop can play out of the box - or the question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet below:

```
Log.e("videopath","videopath");

AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();

File root1 = new File(GoaPoliceApp.reportPath);
if (!root1.exists()) {
      root1.mkdirs();
}

file = new File(root1,"Vid_Recorded_on_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4");

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
}     

fis.close();
fos.close();
mType = 1;
aMedia.setmNMediaType(mType);
aMedia.setmNMediaPath(file.getAbsolutePath().toString());
aMedia.setmNPublished("1");
aMedArr = new ArrayList<Media>();
aMedArr.add(aMedia);
GoaPoliceApp.mMedArr.addAll(aMedArr);
/*aDetails.mMediaArr.add(aMedia);
GoaPoliceApp.mReportArr.add(aDetails);*/
//showMail();

Log.e("videopath",file.getAbsolutePath().toString());
```

Comment: I edited this into the question for you. In future, please use the "edit" link below the question to add additional information to your question - answers are just for solutions to your problem.